# SKSpriteNodes not appearing

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So i currently think i have set up these sprite nodes fine and they should be appearing but i cannot figure it out why they are not showing up in the simulator. Both the background image(bg.png) and the "bird" node appear but none of the nodes inside spawnPipes method are appearing. I am newish to using SpriteKit so it could be something obvious.

Sprite node method:

```
-(void)spawnPipes;
{

    int random = (arc4random() % (int)self.frame.size.height-150)+250;

    //Add pipe end
    SKSpriteNode *upperPipe = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"goldend.png"];
    upperPipe.size = CGSizeMake(70, 25);
    upperPipe.position = CGPointMake(450, random);

    //Add pipe middles
    SKSpriteNode *lowerPipe = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"goldend.png"];
    lowerPipe.size = CGSizeMake(70, 25);
    lowerPipe.position = CGPointMake(upperPipe.position.x, upperPipe.position.y-150);

    //Rest below
    SKSpriteNode *restBelow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"goldmiddle.png"];
    restBelow.size = CGSizeMake(60, lowerPipe.position.y);
    restBelow.position = CGPointMake(lowerPipe.position.x, lowerPipe.position.y-restBelow.size.height/2-lowerPipe.size.height/2+1);

    //Rest above
    SKSpriteNode *restAbove = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"goldmiddle.png"];
    restAbove.size = CGSizeMake(60, self.frame.size.height+upperPipe.position.y);
    restAbove.position = CGPointMake(upperPipe.position.x, upperPipe.position.y+restAbove.size.height/2+upperPipe.size.height/2-2);

    [self addChild:upperPipe];
    [self addChild:lowerPipe];
    [self addChild:restBelow];
    [self addChild:restAbove];

    [pipeArray addObject:upperPipe];
    [pipeArray addObject:lowerPipe];
    [pipeArray addObject:restBelow];
    [pipeArray addObject:restAbove];


}
```

Which is then called in initWithSize:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        //Bird
        bird = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Godcrop.png"];
        bird.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
        bird.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
        bird.zPosition = 3;

        bird.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bird.frame.size];
        bird.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        bird.physicsBody.mass = 0.2;
        bird.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        bird.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        [self addChild:bird];

        //Background
        bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg.png"];
        bg.position = CGPointMake(160, 284);
        bg.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        [self addChild:bg];

        //Spawns pipes
        [self spawnPipes];

        //Set touch boolean for touches began methods
        firstTouch = YES;



    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging or adding a trace to check the x,y locations to see if they are what you expect ?

Comment: Bah! Obvious! It was the x,y location - thanks heaps!

Comment: Also - I suggest you use arc4random_uniform (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) instead of arc4random together with the modulus operator. That way you'll avoid modulus bias.